# Datastage Compactible Version for 11.7.0.0

Tags: operating-system, migration, version, datastage

Hi I want to know compactible version of OS for Datastage 11.7.0.0.

I referred to IBM Document, it says "Windows Server 2016 Standard Edition" is latest version which is compactible.

https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=7FE40FD076CF11E7ACE8EE5CF6073F72&osPlatforms=Windows&mandatoryCapIds=30%7C47%7C9%7C16%7C26&optionalCapIds=7%7C24%7C70%7C186%7C61

As we already have Windows server 2022 version available, Just wanted to make sure we still need to use 2016 version for Datasatge 11.7.0.0

Regards,
Arpitha P

Checked in IBM Website for details, need clarification on it

Answer (score 0):

IBM introduced support for Windows 2019 standard edition with the Info Server 11.7.1.1 release; support for windows server 2022 has not been officially announced. So to be conservative you should run your current 11.7.0 on a supported platform, ie win server 2016.